# Automatically click canvas object

Tags: jquery, selenium, html5-canvas, automated-tests

I want to automatically click a HTML5 canvas object so that I can run my Selenium based automated testing. I went through many resource about automatically triggering click event as in this example: 
[Trigger Click](http://jsfiddle.net/gAxHe/3/)

and this example about making clickable objects in canvas:
[Clicking Canvas Objects](http://jsfiddle.net/9pgWf/559/)

I tried to combine these two examples to make a automatically clickable canvas object. But for some reason I am unable to make it work. I added following code in the second example and expected to automatically  click the object in coordinate(305, 340).

```js
var e = jQuery.Event( "click", { pageX: 305, pageY: 340 } );
$('#myCanvas').trigger(e);
```

`var e = jQuery.Event( "click", { pageX: 305, pageY: 340 } );
$('#myCanvas').trigger(e);`

What am I missing here? Are "clicking on canvas" and "clicking on canvas object" different concepts? Please help.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this issue. I stored the current instance of all the displayed object in a array.

```
var node = new Array();
for((var i in currentProject.rectangle)){
node.push(toArray(currentProject.rectangle[i]));
}
```

All of those objects were assigned an id so I could access those objects and their current position through their id. Later when I had to click to particular object I searched object in that array and get its x and y position and simply override the pageX and pageY values.

```
clickedX = currentProject.rectangle[ID].x;
clickedY = currentProject.rectangle[ID].y;
clickData = {x: clickedX, y: clickedY};

SimulatedClickEvent(clickData);

function SimulatedClickEvent(data) {
this.pageX = data.x;
this.pageY = data.y;
this.preventDefault = function () {
}
}
```

This way I was able to access the objects in canvas without much interfering with canvas.

Answer (score 1):

here's a modification of the sample code you've got above

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    // canvas
    var x = 20;
    var y = 20
    var canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillRect( x, y, 25, 25);

    // canvas click
    $( "canvas" ).on({
        click: function(e){
            alert( e.pageX +", "+ e.pageY );
        }
    });

    // jquery event
    var l = $( "canvas" ).offset().left;
    var t = $( "canvas" ).offset().top;
    var eve = jQuery.Event( "click", { pageX: x+l, pageY: y+t } );
    $( "canvas" ).trigger( eve );

});
```

here's a working example >> http://jsfiddle.net/goutgffw/1

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I am trying to click to a particular object in the canvas not the entire canvas. For example, a clickable rectangle at coordinate (300,100). Since canvas does not keep the reference of its object so it seems tricky to automatically click.

Comment: do you know what the coordinate is? or will the coordinate change?

Comment: For test purpose yes I know what the coordinate will be, however in real use these objects can be dragged so their coordinates can change.

Comment: ah ok, i think i get it now, i've updated the answer above to include a modification of the code in your question as well as a working jsfiddle link

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I finally solved this issue. I stored the current instance of all the displayed object in a array. All of those objects were assigned an id so I could access those objects and their current position through their id. Later when I had to click to particular object I searched object in that array and get its x and y position and simply override the pageX and pageY values.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the click coordinates on the canvas object. I came across a similar situation where i have to click on a element within a canvas and the following code did the trick.

```
Actions clickAt = new Actions(driver);
clickAt.moveToElement(canvasElement, xCoordinates, yCoordinates).click();
clickAt.build().perform();
```